# Do you say "A robust type horse" or "A robust horse type"?

Tags: word-order, prepositional-phrases, attributive-nouns

What's the correct ordering of words: "A robust type horse" or "A robust horse type" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We would say "a robust type *of* horse" or "a robust breed of horse" to mean 'a horse breed known for its robustness'.

It is not impossible to omit the preposition **of** after **type**, but the preposition tends to be used far more often than it is omitted.

We could also say "a robust horse breed" or "a robust horse type", though "horse type" is used far less often than "horse breed".